# Tensorflow 2.0 "future proof" way of using tf.feature_columns in tf.keras subclass api?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I see there are some ways of using features columns wrapped in a tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures layer:

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns#create_a_feature_layer

This suggests passing datasets into @tf.function wrapped "def call" methods?

I don't see any mention (yet) of the interaction between tf.data.DataSet and tf.function. Are tf.data.DataSet considered tensors yet for the purpose of tf.function graph cache or will they be?